# Swift wait for closures to finish

Tags: swift, function, asynchronous, closures

I have a problem with asynchronous tasks.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    self.loadRemote {
        log.debug("completed remote data")
    }
    self.loadLocal {
        log.debug("completed local data")
    }
    self.loadAdmin {
        log.debug("completed admin data")
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        log.debug("called completed data")
        completed()
    }
}
```

The following code does not work as I want to. It gets called in the following order:

```
completed local data
called completed data
completed remote data
```

Which is not what I expected to. You can probably imagine that I wanted the order: "local", "remote" and finally "called completed".

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what Dispatch Groups are for. You call "enter" before starting something, and "leave" when you're done. You can then add a notification, which is a block to enqueue whenever all the operations have completed.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    let group = dispatch_group_create()

    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    self.loadRemote {
        log.debug("completed remote data")
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }

    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    self.loadLocal {
        log.debug("completed local data")
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }

    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    self.loadAdmin {
        log.debug("completed admin data")
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        log.debug("called completed data")
        completed()
    }
}
```

Given that all the `load...` methods appear to be asynchronous, there doesn't seem any reason for the initial `dispatch_async` here (but it's possible they are more time consuming on the current queue than they appear).